# Make Changes in Web Application After Publish to the Azure VM

Tags: iis, azure, web-applications, azure-virtual-machine

How can i make changes in my web application after i published it to the Azure virtual machine?

I publish to my Azure Virtual Machine a web application and after i did everything i notice that i forget to delete a button.

What is the most fastest and easiest way to change my project once its on the air? (on the Virtual Machine with all the "ISS" configuration)

general knowledge: i first publish the website using Visual Studio 2013 and created a VM from there too..

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end i just follow the steps i followed in the first time i published and i just overwrite the existing publish..hope that help.